# how i print more than list horizontal in python

Tags: python, list, printing

I want to print more than one list next to each other, separated by a space, and at the end \n

I have tried

```
for x in range(0,len(a)):

        print( a[x]  b[x]  c[x]  Fa[x]  Fb[x]  Fc[x] )

and

 print(*a *b *c *Fa *Fb *Fc, sep = "\t", end = "\n")
```

l want :

for example :

output:

list1  \t    list2   \t   list3  \t   list4

list1  \t    list2   \t   list3  \t   list4

note: float numbers

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
for x in range(0,len(a)):
   print( a[x],  b[x] , c[x] , Fa[x] , Fb[x],  Fc[x],sep="\t" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you simply tried :

```py
print(a,b,c)
[0.2804517047163412, 0.11395161049709557, 0.29469860412828075, 0.32933146417031167, 0.2854623197776399, 0.055986303832889606, 0.10694687020299098, 0.10584766182481475, 0.7343519943136121, 0.11968230671262314] [0.9154867813103891, 0.1250226273551499, 0.5571605292218571, 0.33237687216357636, 0.8470212947991121, 0.5076533292651144, 0.5110466093195829, 0.43454240710303293, 0.9640867660883007, 0.9462132958664978] [0.6983403479101113, 0.7113831823151883, 0.5344539308524074, 0.08967748535250597, 0.3954864501096331, 0.7143445165955005, 0.8239536239592028, 0.7037094601962561, 0.7113321940954429, 0.3327449502568862]
```

By default :

```py
print?
Docstring:
print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

If you do not want the brackets, just expand your list with a star :

```py
print(*a,*b,*c)
0.2804517047163412 0.11395161049709557 0.29469860412828075 0.32933146417031167 0.2854623197776399 0.055986303832889606 0.10694687020299098 0.10584766182481475 0.7343519943136121 0.11968230671262314 0.9154867813103891 0.1250226273551499 0.5571605292218571 0.33237687216357636 0.8470212947991121 0.5076533292651144 0.5110466093195829 0.43454240710303293 0.9640867660883007 0.9462132958664978 0.6983403479101113 0.7113831823151883 0.5344539308524074 0.08967748535250597 0.3954864501096331 0.7143445165955005 0.8239536239592028 0.7037094601962561 0.7113321940954429 0.3327449502568862
```

Comment: I think OP wants just the values printed with spaces between, and tabs between lists. Not sure why though.